# How to create .app file to pkg installer for mac with desktop shortcut icon

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

We have created the xamarin mac application. Now we have build app to pkg installer using iceberg 3rd party tool.

We need to make shortcut icon in the desktop for the Xamarin mac app.

Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

In general this is against the HIG and not something a majority of macOS users would expect. I would strongly suggest against it.

If you want to go down this path, you will likely have to write a post install script that your installer can bundle in an run after install.

Comment: Please can you provide some example script for the Mac OS

Comment: You'll have to research how installer scripts work and likely package in a small application to generate the shortcut. I don't have first hand experience with either